# R: Replace conditioned column value with random sample of remaining column values

Tags: r, data.table, sample

I have a dataset and I want to replace 75% of the `Alevel=="A"` with a random sample of `Alevel!="A"`. I started by finding the count of `Alevel=="A"` and subsequently finding the 75% of that count.

I randomly selected of 75% of ID's with `Alevel=="A"` *but* I then have to assign random values to the `Alevel` of those randomly sampled IDs

First of all I know the `DT[column=="X"][c(subset of dataset),column:="New Value"]` syntax is incorrect, but it's what my instinct with my knowledge of `data.table` lead me too. I have two questions

1. How can I neatly execute my plan to replace 75% of the `Alevel=="A"` with a random sample of `Alevel!="A"` using cleaner, easily readable, and robust `data.table` syntax with the fewest amount of lines possible
2. For future reference, how can I reassign values when I first place a condition on a dataset followed by a subset (e.g. like in my incorrect example of trying `DT[column=="X"][c(subset of dataset),column:="New Value"]`). I know .SD will come into play but I haven't quite grasped how exactly it is used

Below is the code I attempted to use to execute my plan. It's very bulky and it doesn't work and I want to condense it into something more readable and robust.

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(1992)
DT <- data.table(ID=1:1000,Alevel=sample(LETTERS,1000,replace = TRUE))

DT[,table(Alevel)]
(count.ids.w.A <- nrow(DT[Alevel=="A"]))
(count.ids.w.A.to.replace <- round(count.ids.w.A*.75))
values <- DT[Alevel!="A",unique(Alevel)]
DT[Alevel=="A",][sample(count.ids.w.A,count.ids.w.A.to.replace),Alevel:=sample(values,count.ids.w.A.to.replace)]
DT[,table(Alevel)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it that should be robust. This uses the indices for A, selects 75% of them, and then replaces them in `DT` using `sample()` with `setdiff()`

```
# positions for A's
A_sub = DT[Alevel == "A", which = TRUE] 

# select 75% of A subset
A_sub = A_sub[sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), length(A_sub), prob = c(.75, .25), replace = TRUE)] 

# replace your subset of A's
DT[A_sub, Alevel := sample(setdiff(unique(DT$Alevel), "A"), .N, replace = TRUE)] 


DT[,table(Alevel)]
Alevel
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z 
10 43 46 40 40 44 42 45 42 36 45 47 45 31 40 41 44 39 34 31 35 31 39 46 41 23
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really neat

Comment: Sure thing @theneil, let me know if it does not solve your problem!